# Jboss 7 AS - combine standalone.xml loggin configuration and per deployment logging configuration

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

i am using JBoss 7 AS,i have few ear deployed in this JBoss. 
standalone.xml has configured with following logging configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
.
.
.
.
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
.
.
.
.
            <size-rotating-file-handler autoflush="true" name="MAINLOGFILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file path="mainlog.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir"/>
                <append value="true"/>
                <rotate-size value="1m"/>
                <max-backup-index value="1000"/>
            </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Then i tried to add a logging.properties file into one ear META-INF,it woks as expected.
again i wanted to refer a handler (MAINLOGFILE defined in the stanalone.xml) from that logging.properties file (which i have placed in to META-INF of one of ear ).
this is the logging.properties looks like:

```
loggers=my.testpackage

logger.my.testpackage.level=INFO
logger.my.testpackage.handlers=EXTFILE,MAINLOGFILE
logger.my.testpackage.useParentHandlers=true 

    handler.EXTFILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
    handler.EXTFILE.level=ALL
    handler.EXTFILE.formatter=PATTERN
    handler.EXTFILE.properties=autoFlush,append,fileName,suffix
    handler.EXTFILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
    handler.EXTFILE.autoFlush=true
    handler.EXTFILE.append=true
    handler.EXTFILE.fileName=${jboss.server.log.dir}/mytest.log
    handler.EXTFILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd

    formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
    formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
    formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n

    formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
    formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
    formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

But the entries log into the EXTFILE are not logged into the MAINLOGFILE.
My expectation is that each and every entry which is logged into EXTFILE should be visible in the MAINLOGFILE as well

Please help me o find out a way to refer a log handler defined in the standalone.xml from per deployment loggign.properties file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the logging config in your app? You can easily define the logger handlers in jboss logging subsystem that target specific packages or even classes in the apps the are deployed:

```
<!-- all classes in `my.testpackage` package should only print INFO and up into mainlog.-->
<logger category="my.testpackage" use-parent-handlers="true">
   <level name="INFO"/>
   <handlers>
      <handler name="MAINLOGFILE"/>
   </handlers>
</logger>
 <!-- This class should print DEBUG and up into mainlog.-->
<logger category="my.testpackage.SuperImportantClass" use-parent-handlers="true">
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <handlers>
      <handler name="MAINLOGFILE"/>
   </handlers>
</logger>
```

Advantages: you can easily add this configuration via [cli or web admin interface](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Logging_Configuration_in_the_CLI.html) of JBoss and as a great bonus, you can change it at runtime without having to restart the server or your webapp. If you want, you can then make the configuration part of your distribution process e.g. create your own docker image with jboss, with your app deployment and your cli/config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.your suggestion is very good but unfortunately it doesn't fit my requirement(reason is really difficult explain) .configure logging through CLI is also an option but there should be a way to run CLI script automatically when server is started.

Comment: `really difficult explain` ;) I guess you're out of luck then. Per-deployment logging is just that-logging config isolated for your app. As for automated cli execution: while it is possible to do it via custom jboss extension for example, you should honestly make it part of your delivery pipeline. Keep the .cli files in your app if you wish, say `src/main/resources/cli` and execute them during the deployment via shell script of jenkins job. Or make custom jboss start script for it. But life is much easier if you have single source of truth for your config- server config in this case. Good luck